# Evaluate which column should be selected in where clause

Tags: sql

I have a table named Employee with following columns

```
    || Id || Employee_Name || Address
    =================================
    || 1  || Name1         || Add1
    || 2  || Name2         || Add2

    select <column_name> from Employee 
    where column_name = 'ID';
```

Result should be like following

```
    Id
    ===
    1
    2
```

Comment: please tag **one and only one** database

Comment: I am removing the extraneous database tags.  Feel free to add the one that you are using.

Comment: I don't quite follow the issue...what's the problem that you're having?

Comment: Why do you need a Where clause?

Comment: I want to select the column dynamically depending on the result of an another query.

Comment: Google "dynamic sql"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Declare @Table table (Id varchar(25),Employee_name varchar(25), Address varchar(25))
Insert @Table values
(101,'A1','B1' ),
(102,'A2','B2' ),
(103,'A3','B3' ),
(104,'A3','B4' ),
(105,'A3','B5' )

select field_content as selected_column_content
 from (
select
field_name, field_content
FROM
(Select cast(id as varchar(max)) as id, 
        cast(Employee_name as varchar(max)) as Employee_name,
        cast(address as varchar(max)) as address from @Table) A
unpivot (
    field_content 
    FOR field_name 
    IN (a.id,a.Employee_name,a.address)
    ) AS unpvt
where upper(field_name) = upper('id')
) unpvt1
unpivot 
( Value FOR 
  Column_Name in (unpvt1.field_name)) piv
;
```